# new_time function in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, oracle, t-sql

Is there a function or a workaround in SQL Server 2005 that is equivalent to the new_time() function in oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not equivalent functionality to Oracle's NEW_TIME() function in SQL Server 2005.  It was added to SQL Server 2008 - [DATETIMEOFFSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx).

CLR UDF would be the most likely alternative.